# What database driver should be used to access AWS Aurora?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

What ruby database driver should be used to access AWS Aurora?
We intend to use this db as the backend for a Rails app.

Comment: It should be compliant with your MySQL driver of choice.

Comment: 2nd that: http://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/faqs/

Answer (score 7):

as stated by Amazon, Aurora is 100% compatible to MySql at the service layer, so, you should use the driver you use to connect to MySql.

Answer (score 7):

Question was edited after this answer, this answer is for the JVM ecosystem.

At a conference at re:Invent 2016, it was mentioned that using MariaDB driver can make failovers faster since the driver register the IPs of the  nodes so your application don't have to wait for DNS propagation in case of a failover.

At around the 28 minutes mark https://youtu.be/duf5uUsW3TM?t=27m40s.

---

**Update March 5th, 2018**

Since this answer, the support has been officially documented. See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/failover-and-high-availability-with-mariadb-connector-j-for-2x-driver/#specifics-for-amazon-aurora for the specifics.

---

**Update February 11th, 2022**

MariaDB driver 3.x unfortunately dropped the support for Aurora since they [lacked the support of the community for PRs and testing infrastructure](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-connector-j-303-release-notes/).

AWS is developing its own [JDBC driver adapted for Aurora](https://awslabs.github.io/aws-mysql-jdbc/) but it's still in preview.

Comment: See https://mariadb.org/mariadb-connectorj-failover-support-case-amazon-aurora/ for a deep explanation of that use case